# SQL Query with criteria on three tables

Tags: sql, oracle

So here I have the structure of database:

[image: Tables]

The situation is as follows, let's say I have a child element "Sivu" with ID 1294652442332 and few more attributes (not important). 
I need to select Pages (page is parent element for Sivu) that are parents of my Sivu. Current working oracle DB query for this is

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT parent.oid as parentid
                , parent.otype as parenttype
                , child.oid as childid
                , child.otype as childtype
                , child.ncode as ncode
                , child.nrank as nrank
FROM
  assetrelationtree child
        , assetrelationtree parent
        , Page parentasset
WHERE
  child.oid = 1294652442332 
  AND child.otype = 'Sivu'
  AND child.nparentid != 0
  AND child.ncode = '-'
  AND parent.nid = child.nparentid
  AND parent.otype = 'Page'
  AND parentasset.id = parent.oid
  AND parentasset.status != 'VO'
ORDER BY   
  nrank
```

Now, in the picture You will see that there is a siteplan table (OID field holds Page ID). It also holds one more important thing about the Page (parent element of Sivu). The important field I want to know is NCODE.
So basically, I want to modify this query to select Page elements which have the NCODE fields in table siteplantree has a specific value (NCODE = 'Placed').
I tried to modify query but I'm stuck and I don't even know if it's possible with a single select:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT parent.oid as parentid
                , parent.otype as parenttype
                , child.oid as childid
                , child.otype as childtype
                , child.ncode as ncode
                , child.nrank as nrank
FROM
    assetrelationtree child
        , assetrelationtree parent
       , Page parentasset
       , siteplantree siteplan
WHERE
    child.oid = 1294652442332
    AND child.otype = 'Sivu'
    AND child.nparentid != 0
    AND child.ncode = '-'
    AND parent.nid = child.nparentid
    AND parent.otype = 'Page'
    AND parentasset.id = parent.oid
    AND parentasset.status != 'VO'

  AND siteplan.ncode = 'Placed'
  AND siteplan.oid = child.nparentid
ORDER BY
    nrank
```

Hopefully I have described the problem, so that You can understand. If some things are not clear, please let me know and I will update description.

Comment: I'm guessing the missing comma here: `Page parentasset siteplantree siteplan` is a typo (should read `Page parentasset, siteplantree siteplan`)

Comment: Yes, I rewrote the query fast when submitting question and made that type, however, that's not the issue. The second query returns empty results.

Comment: try changing `AND siteplan.oid = child.nparentid` to `AND siteplan.oid = parentasset.id`

Comment: Looks like it work, lol. So simple, thank You, this saved my day! Will investigate and try to understand why didn't it work.

Comment: @paul . . . You should put your comment into an answer, which can then be upvoted and accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `AND siteplan.oid = child.nparentid` to `AND siteplan.oid = parentasset.id`